# (can't run exe app on wine) -- err:module:attach_process_dlls "MSVCP140.dll" failed to initialize, aborting

Tags: linux, debian, wine

I have Debian 9, and wine from Debian repo:

```
wine --version
```

> wine-1.8.7 (Debian 1.8.7-2)

1. I downloaded PokerStars.exe
2. Run command `wine /path/to/exe/`

   2.1. Installation has been complited.
3. When I run PokerStars from menu Application (in XFCE) I get only it:

[image]

3.1 After that's PokerStars window hide:

3.2 In `ps -A` no processes about wine/PokerStars/etc around wine.

4. If I run installed PokerStars from terminal:

`wine '/home/misdeed/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/PokerStars/PokerStars.exe'`

I get errors:

> err:winediag:xrandr12_init_modes Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.
>
> err:winediag:xrandr12_init_modes Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.
>
> wine: Call from 0x7b83ae8c to unimplemented function api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll._initialize_onexit_table, aborting
>
> err:module:attach_process_dlls "MSVCP140.dll" failed to initialize, aborting
>
> err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\Program Files\PokerStars\PokerStars.exe" failed, status 80000100

===

Here extended information about video and drivers:

```
lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
```

> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV44M [GeForce Go 6400] (rev a1)

Driver:

> [    24.338] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
>
> [    24.344]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
>
> [    24.344]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
>
> [    24.356] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.137  Thu Sep 14 13:13:03 PDT 2017

Comment: Is MSVCP140.dll part of the PokerStars package and can you find it in either the app or system directory of Wine's C: drive?  If not, you will need to find that somewhere and manually add it.  It's a C runtime library from Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, its have: http://i.imgur.com/1sCsYXr.png

Comment: @fixer1234 I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solve this problem:

1: I downloaded wine 2.2 source code.

2: `cd` to tar.xz wine-2.2

3: Extracted tar.xz and `cd` in wine-2.2

4 (or 0): **`apt-get install xorg-dev libx11-dev`** (Most important step)

5: `./configure`, `make`, `make install`

6: `./wine /path/to/exe`

PROFIT!

It helps me:

[image]

Comment: Kudos!  How you figured that out and why that fixed it might be educational as well.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 I think the problem was with the lack of packages, since I have a minimum debian. Thanks for help again!

Answer (score 2):

Getting things working in Wine is 1/3 science, 1/3 art, and 1/3 magic.  It usually isn't as simple as just running the installer in Wine.  You may need helper packages, DDLs from Windows, or other tweaks.  Using PlayOnLinux to install the package is often helpful.  Success varies with distros and versions of everything, what else is running, phases of the moon, ...

WineHQ has a [database](https://appdb.winehq.org/) of 26,000 apps.  [PokerStars](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2899) experience is a little dated, but generally pretty good with Ubuntu and Mint, so that's encouraging for Debian.  But getting it to run does entail some special configuration.

The PokerStars link above includes recommended tweaks.  Excerpted details:

> **Installing the PokerStars Client:**
>
> - Install Wine (have FontForge installed before building Wine from source)
> - Download the PokerStars client. Install using the command 'wine PokerStarsInstall.exe'
>
> **Installing the Microsoft Arial (if needed) and Tahoma fonts:**
>
> - Download the Arial fonts. Install using the command 'wine arial32.exe'
> - Download the Tahoma fonts. Install using the command 'wine tahoma32.exe'
>
> **Running PokerStars without Xfce/KDE/Gnome:**
>
> - `wine "C:\Program Files\PokerStars\PokerStarsUpdate.exe"`
>
> **Manually resizing table windows workaround:**
>
> - You can resize and then redraw the table using the F5 key by adding the following into the `~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/PokerStars/user.ini` file under [Options]: f5redrawtable=1 (won't work properly if window is resized beyond min/max size)
>
> **FONTS**
>
> It has been reported several times that the lobby/table fonts for the table list/player names/chip amounts don't render well or don't show up at all. I would try the following first to correct the font problem:
>
> - The Wine package for your distro might not have been built using FontForge. Try installing FontForge and then build Wine from source.
> - Install the Arial (if needed) and Tahoma fonts {See HOWTO above}
>
> **WINDOW MANAGER**
>
> Running the PokerStars Client without allowing the window manager to control the windows makes Manually resizing table windows work correctly. However, the cursor in the chat box still tabs and mouseover player information still doesn't work. You will have to sacrifice desktop integration though if you choose to run PokerStars this way. Run 'winecfg'/Graphics tab and uncheck 'Allow the window manager to control the windows' to set.
>
> **WARNING:** I recommend not using other programs while playing PokerStars this way.

You will want to read all of the detail at that link, as well as the comments.

All that said, it isn't clear whether that will solve the specific problem in your question.  It looks like it was unable to load a driver, and it isn't clear what that refers to.  Using PlayOnLinux might help with that.

Comment: Ok, i do it! All has been complited is fine.

Comment: When I run Pokerstars, i see window, all ok, but that just kill: http://i.imgur.com/nLa0oSx.png.

Comment: I also run from terminal and get error: **...
err:winediag:xrandr12_init_modes Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.
wine: Call from 0x7b83ae8c to unimplemented function api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll._initialize_onexit_table, aborting
err:module:attach_process_dlls "MSVCP140.dll" failed to initialize, aborting
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:...** I can't know hoe to fix it (((

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk, it looks like at least part of the problem relates to your graphics card driver.  I'm afraid I'm not fluent enough with Wine problems to get you across the finish line on this one.  But as Biswapriyo commented, add all of this detail to your question so that someone else will have a better shot at helping you solve this.

Comment: @fixer1234, ok, I add more details! Thanks for answer, and reply.